# Java Quaqua Popup Menu

Tags: java, macos, swing

I have a Java Swing application running on OSX that uses Quaqua. All the TextFields and TextAreas have a popup menu on right click. This must be done by Quaqua as it is not standard in Swing.

My question is:

How do I set my own Actions on the popup menu?

Please Note. This is a question about **Quaqua** popup menus NOT any Swing popup menu. If you are not familiar about Quaqua then please don't answer.

Comment: Thanks Balaswamy vaddeman but you have **NOT** answered the question. I know how to add popup menus in Swing. The question refers to popup menus that are added by Quaqua Not by me.

Answer (score 1):

A pop-up menu is the same as a regular menu. The [Swing tutorial about menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) covers how to use them, how to insert entries, ... . Reading that tutorial should get you started

Comment: Robin, thanks but you have NOT answered the question. I want to know how to change the default Action on the Quaqua popup menu. Quaqua has created the popup menu (not me) but I need to change the Action to be my special Action.

Comment: @Lyndon Sorry I misinterpreted the question, I suggest you add this comment to your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The popup menu set by Quaqua can be removed by setting a client property:

```
myTextField.putClientProperty("Quaqua.TextComponent.showPopup", Boolean.FALSE);
```

You can then add your own MouseListener to handle creating your own pop up menu.

I haven't figured out, however, to make this change global, and so I have to set the client property on each of my text fields individually, which is a bit of a pain.